# Adding Multiple PhotoImage to TKinter Canvas

Tags: image, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm running into a problem that makes me feel like I've been beating my head against a wall.  I'm trying to get multiple (2 for starters) photoimages to be added to a tkinter canvas.  Here is the code below:

```
def build_frame(screenHeight, screenWidth):
    canvas = Canvas(root, bg = 'blue', height = screenHeight, width = screenWidth)

    player = create_random_player()
    enemy = create_random_enemy()
    display_player_image(canvas, player)
    display_enemy_image(canvas, enemy)

    bind_all_keys(canvas, player)

    canvas.pack()


def display_player_image(canvas, player):
    tkImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(player.playerImgPath))
    player.playerId = canvas.create_image(player.playerPositionX, player.playerPositionY, image = tkImage, anchor = NE)
    player.playerImg = tkImage


def display_enemy_image(canvas, enemy):
    tkImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(enemy.enemyImgPath))
    enemy.enemyId = canvas.create_image(enemy.enemyPositionX, enemy.enemyPositionY, image = tkImage, anchor = NE)
    enemy.enemyImg = tkImage


def create_random_player():
    return Player(0, randint(0,9), randint(0,9), randint(0,9), PLAYER_IMAGE_PATH, 50, 0)


def create_random_enemy():
    return Enemy(0, randint(0,9), randint(0,9), randint(0,9), ENEMY_IMAGE_PATH, 150, 150)
```

I've made sure that I store a reference to the image and I know that the images aren't at the same location but I can't understand why the second one isn't appearing.  I've even put in print statements to check to make sure the image is being created and it is at the given coordinates along with an ID that I can use to identify it.